# can someone tell me why my overflow-x is effecting my menu border?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I added an overflow-x: hidden; so that the horizontal scrollbar won't show and now it's affecting the border I have on my menu bar the right side of the menu bar is not showing its border and when I take the overflow-x code out of CSS the border comes back is there any way to keep the scroll bar hidden and get the right side of the border to show thanks!

CSS:

```
*{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1{
    font:bold 16px tahoma;
}
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
    display: block;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
section{
    font: 12px Verdana;
}
#big_wrapper{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
#top_header{
    background: transparent;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#top_menu{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #BDBDBD, #E6E6E6, #BDBDBD);
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;

}
#top_menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font: bold 14px tahoma;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="big_wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <img src="iadt.jpg" height="100" width="300"> </img>
            </header>

            <center><nav id="top_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Application">Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Iamdrivingtoday.com/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>  </center>
```

Comment: if you have a url for the page, you should provide it.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/24xjii8/8

Comment: that's a screenshot. What I meant was a link to the actual page.

Comment: its not uploaded yet. im redesigning it.

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting this answered if you upload it to a temporary location.

Comment: The depends a great deal on what sort of webhosting you have and how your website is set up. It would require a separate question, and it might not be a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because your `#big_wrapper`'s width equals `#top_menu`'s width which is `1000px`. Remember that when you define `border: 1px solid black;` in your `#top_menu` then it will add 1 pixel on every side of your `#top_menu`. Simply saying that your `#top_menu`'s width is now `1002px`. To overcome that problem you have 2 choices below:

1. Decrease the `#top_menu`'s width into `998px;`
2. Add `box-sizing: border-box;` into your `#top_menu`